# How to get request.getRemoteUser() value

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application where I want to check if the remoteUser is available. How do I need to configure the tomcat to get a remoteUser in my local copy. The line of code that I am executing is as follows. For my local copy of the codebase, request.getRemoteUser() always return null. Any help appreciated.

```
if (request.getRemoteUser()!= null){
        myBean.setName(nameFromUser);
}
```

Comment: Have you configured a [login](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) for your application? If you are not logging in you will always get null for the remote user.

Comment: Can you throw some light on how to configure a login for my application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Valve or a Realm on container-side which sets the UserPrincipal into the request.

As done [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.catalina/com.springsource.org.apache.catalina/7.0.12/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/BasicAuthenticator.java#157):

```
157  principal = context.getRealm().authenticate(username, password);
158  if (principal != null) {
159      register(request, response, principal, Constants.BASIC_METHOD,
160               username, password);
161      return (true);
162  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat, set tomcatAuthentication="false".